# Не появляется плеер на заблокированном экране

Tags: swift4, ios10

Поставил флажок Audio в Background Modes:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настроил Аудиосессию:

```
import UIKit

import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var audio: AVAudioPlayer?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do {

            try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [])
            try audioSession.setActive(true)

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        do {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "example", withExtension: "mp3")
            audio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        audio?.play()

        var nowPlayingInfo = [String : Any]()
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] = "Artist"
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] = "My Track"

        if let image = UIImage(named: "image") {
            nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size) { size in
                return image
            }
        }

        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime] = audio!.currentTime
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration] = audio!.duration
        nowPlayingInfo[MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate] = audio!.rate

        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo

        return true
    }
}
```

При блокировке экрана звук продолжает проигрываться, но плеер на заблокированном экране не появляется. Подскажите, что не доделал/не так делаю?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте данную строчку в конец функции `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`:

```
UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
```

Так Вы оповестите систему о том, что хотите управлять проигрывателем через специальное меню, появляющееся при блокировке экрана.

Также хочу отметить, что в [официальной документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623126-beginreceivingremotecontrolevent) рекомендуется использовать вместо `beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()` методы класса `MPRemoteCommandCenter` для приложений с поддержкой iOS 7.1 и более новых версий данной операционной системы. Ниже приведу пример работы с `MPRemoteCommandCenter` (данный код используйте вместо `UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`):

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
    guard let audio = self.audio else {
        return .commandFailed
    }
    if !audio.isPlaying {
        audio.play()
        return .success
    }
    return .commandFailed
}
commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
    guard let audio = self.audio else {
        return .commandFailed
    }
    if audio.isPlaying {
        audio.pause()
        return .success
    }
    return .commandFailed
}
```

Comment: судя по описанию, beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents - устаревший метод, использовавшийся в ios до 7.1: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623126-beginreceivingremotecontrolevent

Comment: @xhr Я добавил в свой ответ вариант решения с помощью `MPRemoteCommandCenter`.